# How to download a file in IE10 using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to download a file using selenium webdriver but the test stops as soon as it encounters the IE10 download dialog box. How do I click save on this dialog box? Will Robot API help?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: [This has been asked many times, please search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium+download+file)

The long and more correct answer: As of now (2013/10), it can't be done via WebDriver. [It's one of the most requested features for the Selenium project.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=95)

You can try one of these things:

1. Make a request for the specified link using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/). You can even download the file this way, although the usual practice is just to assert a 200 OK response to make sure that the file can be downloaded (since you usually don't really need the file when you're testing your application).
2. [Snatch the file using any Java approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) Or [this tool](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java) made by someone to be used with Selenium.
3. Use the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class to simply press <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or something. But beware, this will only work for your particular browser and OS. It will most likely break on any other configuration.